# Django DRF works, but gives error back to AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-rest-framework

I have kind of successfully implemented an AJAX request for to `PUT` in DRF. **Everything is working** fine, but the error callback in AJAX is triggered:

drf part:

```
class ProductDataViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication,]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def put(self, request):
        ...
        return Response(data = "OK", status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

AJAX part:

```
let write2db = function ( data ) {
    
    let csrf_token = $('[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').attr('value');
    $.ajax({ url: "api/products/",
             type: "PUT",
             data: JSON.stringify(data),
             dataType: "string",
             headers: { 'X-CSRFTOKEN': csrf_token,
                        "Content-type": "application/json"  },
             success: function (request, status, error) {
                 console.log(request, "--", status, "---", error)
                 window.location = "/pe/?message=success&status=success"; 
             },
             error: function ( request, status, error ) { 
                 window.location = `/pe/?message=${error} - ${request.responseText}&status=danger`; 
             }
    });
};
```

when using this JSON:

```
data = {'number': '2', 'data': {'name': 'brand new', 'price': '2.4'}}
```

in the console I get:

> "GET
> /pe/?message=No%20conversion%20from%20text%20to%20string%20-%20%22product%20updated%22&status=danger
> HTTP/1.1" 200 8188

short:

> No conversion from text to string.

Comment: `dataType: "string",` but you are returning JSON. `dataType` refers to the format you want your response in

Comment: if you post a reply I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataType: "string"`, but you are returning JSON. `dataType` refers to the format you want your response in. Your error looks like it might be getting caught in the format of the response.

Try setting `dataType: 'json'`